# Displaying variables in size order (numbers)

Tags: python, variables

Is it possible to display a set of variables in numerical size order without resorting to a list? 
(There are many questions relating to list size order, but none relating to displaying variables this way)
   e.g.

```
variable1= random.randint(1,999)
variable2= random.randint(1,999)
variable3= random.randint(1,999)
```

So would there be any efficient way to print these in order of size, even if I don't know the sizes?

Comment: No there is not any obvious way to print some variables in sorted order without **resorting to a list**

Comment: You can do it with a series of nested `if` statements, but that quickly will get out-of-hand for more than about 3 variables. What do you have against putting them in a list and sorting it?

Comment: So you want to print a list of numbers that are sorted but you don't want to sort the numbers first?

Comment: I was simply interested to see if there was another way to do it: one that was quicker and didn't involve messing around with lists

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use conditional if statements.

Probably not the most efficient way to do it but:

```
x = 1
y = 2
z = 3
if z > y and z > x:
    print z
#and so on
```

I think you get what I was going for. It's probably not ideal to do it this way, just what came to mind.

Comment: I don't think that's the size the OP is talking about. It's the numerical value stored in the variables (as stated in the question).

Comment: @martineau after rereading I think you are right. I will edit, since it is now easier.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, with a series of `if ... elif` statements, where the complexity grows each time you add a value/variable.

Why wouldn't you want to use a list though? It would be much simpler.

If you *need* or *really want* to use variables, then how about this approach:

```py
import random

variable1 = random.randint(1,999)
variable2 = random.randint(1,999)
variable3 = random.randint(1,999)

var_name_list = []
var_name_list.append('variable1')
var_name_list.append('variable2')
var_name_list.append('variable3')

for value in sorted( [ eval(var_name) for var_name in var_name_list ] ):
    print(value)
```

Comment: I was seeing if there was an easier way than using a list

Comment: There isn't... I can't see how there could be!

Comment: I wasn't sure, but then again I don't know everything so I decided to check as (because such a thing doesn't exist) I couldn't find any documentation disproving or proving it